# Javascript looping until condition met

Tags: javascript, loops

how to break a loop until variable 'i' met the condition that 'i' should in certain value. After break, wait 1 minutes then run the same loop again.

Comment: You lost me at `break a loop until`. You don't break a loop *until*, since you can only break it *once*.

Comment: Did you try looking for "loop javascrip" or "javascript interval" ? Do it.

Comment: break the loop when your condition returns true, wait 1 minute and use recursion to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this:

```
var timer = setInterval(function () { doTask() }, 60000);

function doTask() {
    while (condition) {

    }
}
```